# NFS Share Access Problem from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, nfs, azure-data-factory, fileshare

Want to connect a NFS Share to Data Factory. After inserting our share hostname, user and password, when we click to test connection, we receive the following error:

Error occurred when trying to access the file in Folder '\[server_name][folder_name]$', File filter: '*'. The network path was not found. Activity ID: XXX.

It is a NFS Share on premise and it is not in Azure Environment and it is specifically used in our internal environment.

Does somebody have experienced the same kind of problem or do you have any idea?

Comment: How does ADF reach the on-premise NFS share? Is the firewall opened for Azure services?

Comment: You probably need a ADF Self-Hosted Integration Runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I ran into the same issue